# How to decrypt identity section in web config?

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I have the following encrypted identity tag in my web config  file-:

```
<identity configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
          <CipherValue>iafzB3KzsJNARz+5zffLyV2Rzuu/UjLdFr3D8jHfJHKGC6u3jlFB8f/FeveEsQqNP981rbFafKlXXdyG/DGMMkowWbnkQVYaffIUDkvk19jIntsFqufWYJWOO95CceKjjZPeNHh8FCadp1et5Th/mCUtz8xsQ9s8e92t64J8jlg=</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
      </EncryptedKey>
    </KeyInfo>
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>MWlwJley/C3TbezWLE+wPHo22L1Tog6xCTm999SoWkUzvIz+FdrVgBw3+x5GexO7BNG6KycamWqSdCl+1pD4a/rWfYbY26We5AgrPh20kTN7WKf9noFmCg==</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
</identity>
```

I want to know that what keyword should  i use in this command prompt to decrypt identity section in web config?
 currently i am using this-:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf identity  C
```

:\inetpub\vhosts\kimpolling.nl\httpdocs
But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decrypt the encrypted Web.config file contents, if you want to, by running `aspnet_regiis.exe` with the `-pd`option. The syntax is the same as the syntax for encrypting Web.config file contents with the `-pe` option, except that you do not specify a Protected Configuration provider.

Example:

```
aspnet_regiis -pd "connectionStrings" -app "/MyApplication"
```

The above will decrypt the `connectionStrings`.

**[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

Comment: yes i know and suppose i want to decrypt  the above identity section so what should i use in place of connection string in above comment made by you.

Comment: You would use identity

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `system.web/identity` not just `identity`?